# What is the best way to create a DRY content model hierarchy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, architecture

I have content management system for an iOS app built with rails. Right now there a are three different types of content. The first two are just strings uploaded into a textfield by the user. One is twitter handles and hashtags, the other is URLs. The second type is photos.

The user can upload as many individual instances of these types content as he/she wants to given a *feed* which will is the then passed to the iOS app via an API call to display.

The current approach I am using is to have Feed, Picture, Twitter, and Webpage models. When the user crates a new Feed, they then associate the appropriate content with that feed via a one to many relationship between each Feed instance it's content instances.

When it comes time to display to content the user has uploaded, a GET request for a given stream is generated and the Feed model then does the following awful thing determine what type of content should be shown:

```
 def Feed.get_content_for_feed(feed_id)
    return self.map_type_to_class(feed_id).get_content_for_feed(feed_id)
  end

  private

  def Feed.map_type_to_class(feed_id)
    feed_type_id = Feed.find(feed_id).feed_type_id
    not_yet_implemented = nil
    case stream_type_id
      when 1
        return Webpages
      when 2
        return Pictures
      when 3
        return not_yet_implemented
      when 4
        return Twitter
      when 5
        return not_yet_implemented
      when 6
        return not_yet_implemented
      when 7
        return not_yet_implemented
      when 8
        return not_yet_implemented
      else
        return nil

    end
  end
```

Then each content class implements a `get_content_for_feed` method to return the content:

```
def Twitter.get_content_for_feed(feed_id)
    tweet_urls = self.where(:feed_id => feed_id.to_i)
    if tweet_urls.empty?
      return []
    else
      return tweet_urls
    end
  end
```

So it just returns the appropriate class. This works, but I know that it is wrong, but I am not sure what I would be doing.

Comment: What is `feed_type_id` seems like `feed_type` should handle this through a `polymorphic` relationship. e.g. `belongs_to :feed_type, polymorphic: true` then the `feed_type` will specify the relationship class. [See Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Yes, polymorphism seems to be close to what I'm getting at here. But I don't want one resource to be shared by a bunch of others. I want one resource to be able to  draw from a bunch of others, in this case, different types of content.

Comment: Then why use `feed_type_id` why not just `feed_type` and then you could do `feed_type = 'Twitter'` or `feed_type = 'Webpages'` and then instead of your case statement just use `feed_type.classify.constantize` this will create what you want in a much cleaner fashion. `classify` will turn a string into proper class case so snake case `class_name` becomes `ClassName` single words just get capitalized. Then `constantize` turns them into an actual `Class`. So `"pictures".classify.constantize.all` would be the same as `Pictures.all`

Comment: Yes, this works as well, but I just feel like there must be a better way. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: I will see if I can devise a proper answer for your issue to illustrate what I am intending to say. I just want to make sure I understand a `Feed` `has_many :webpages` or a `Feed` `has_many :pictures` etc. a single `Feed` will not encompass both `webpages and pictures` is that correct?

Comment: "Is there a better way?" questions, especially for code that is working, belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes that is correct.

Comment: Just a few small points about your `case` statement. Firstly, there is no need for any of the `return`s. Secondly, if you prefer, you could write: `when 3, 5, 6, 7, 8; not_yet_implemented`. Thirdly, since `not_yet_implemented #=> nil`, and you have `else; nil`, you could simply remove the cases dealing with `3, 5, 6, 7, 8` (unless you wish to draw attention to the fact that eventually there will be 8 cases).

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you

```
class User
  has_many :feeds
  has_many :twitters, through: :feeds, source: :feedable, source_type: 'Twitter'
  has_many :webpages, through: :feeds, source: :feedable, source_type: 'Webpage'
  has_many :pictures, through: :feeds, source: :feedable, source_type: 'Picture'
end

class Feed
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feedable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Now your `feeds` table will need `feedable_id` and `feedable_type` then the associations will work as expected. e.g.

```
Website.create name: "website", url: "http://www.example.com"
user = User.create name: "User"
feed = user.feeds.build
feed.feedable = Website.find_by_name("website")
feed.save
```

I don't have a ton of experience with this sort of has_many through polymorphic but conceptually this should work for you. In case this does not solve the problem completely there are a ton of SO questions and articles if you [Google polymorphic has_many through](https://www.google.com/search?q=has_many+polymorphic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=polymorphic+has_many+through).